# picture auto-enhance algorithm

Tags: c#, image

I am working on c# app that enhance pictures automatically.
What i mean by "auto" is that all the user has to do is point to a picture and the application figures out what needs to be improved and improve it.

Obviously since it is not targetting some area within the picture, it won't be perfect but it is very easy to use. I have seen an algorithm that does this but i can't find it.

It would be great if someone knows the name of such algorithm or library that does this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The term "enhance" is a bit generic. The "enhance" button in a typical photo editor does something like a Histogram Equalization, possibly along with a white balance adjustment. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a library, use [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It is a C# wrapper for OpenCV, and is currently the most comprehensive image-processing library available.

It has functions for histrogram equalization, and any other filters you may neeed.

Answer (score 0):

Look up convolution matrix (in general) and unsharp masking. Also gaussian and blur filters.

Answer (score 0):

[Histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) in general does a pretty good job. I did this with php once, you can [view](http://kishorkundan.blogspot.com/) it if you want. (mind you that the desired result can be much more interesting than wht you see there)

It usually will do the job, but u r looking for more then u will have to look into the suggestions pointed out by @satya.

This is what i know obv, there must be tons of other things.